# I want to be able to "walk" a nested XSD using lxml from Python 3

Tags: python, xsd, lxml

I know how to walk a basic XSD with lxml with Python 3

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#
# Go through an XSD, listing attributes and entities
#

import argparse
from lxml import etree

def do_element(elmnt):
     nam = elmnt.get('name')
     if len(elmnt) != 0:
        # Entity
        print("Entity: ", nam, " Type: ",elmnt.get('type','None'))
     else:
        # Attribute
        if nam != None:
             print("Attrib: ", nam, " Type: ",elmnt.get('type','None') )

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='test')
    parser.add_argument('-d',action='store_true',help='debugging')

    parser.add_argument('infile')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    xsd_prs = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
    xsd_doc = etree.parse(args.infile, xsd_prs)
    xsd_doc.xinclude()

    walkall = xsd_doc.getiterator()
    for elmnt in walkall:
        do_element(elmnt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which invokes do_element for every tag for the inputted XSD which in turn spits out some data about the attributes. The problem is that when I have an XSD with an import (in my current directory) so:

AAA.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema 
   elementFormDefault="qualified"
   targetNamespace="AAA"
   version="1"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:AAA="AAA"
   xmlns:BBB="BBB">
   <xs:import namespace="BBB" schemaLocation="BBB.xsd"/>
   <xs:element name="StringAttribute" type="xs:string">
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="ComplexEntity" type="BBB:ComplexEntityType">
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and BBB.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema 
   elementFormDefault="qualified"
   targetNamespace="BBB"
   xmlns:BBB="BBB"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:complexType name="ComplexEntityType">
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="NestedString" type="xs:string">
         </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>   
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I would expect that by running with the file file: AAA.xsd, I could walk the definitions and into the namespace BBB. It doesn't happen. It gets to the element Item but will not decompose further in the ComplexType defined in BBB.xsd. I have tried reparsing xsd_doc as follows:

```
xsd_doc = etree.parse(args.infile)
xsd = etree.XMLSchema(xsd_doc)
```

and lxml blows up with:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'type': References from this schema to components in the namespace 'subtypes' are not allowed, since not indicated by an import statement., line 35
```

The import is definitely there. Why doesn't it get followed?

Comment: I think you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The other examples on this subject on stackexchange were partial, but I have added complete functioning code with example XSDs that demonstrate this.

Comment: IMHO it is not strange that `etree.parse()` does not return a composite tree containing all the definitions from both AAA.xsd and BBB.xsd. For a standard XML parser, there is nothing special about the `import` element; it does not get "followed".

Comment: Standard parsers do take imports/inserts into account because without it they would be unable to understand the XSD or XML. An example would be GenerateDS, which converts XSD structures into Python structures. Unfortunately, it does so without a clearly defined parser that can be repurposed.

Comment: The generateDS distribution provides a preprocessing script that resolves includes (and imports, I think): http://www.davekuhlman.org/generateDS.html#includes-the-xml-schema-include-element. This script uses lxml (source: https://bitbucket.org/dkuhlman/generateds/src/tip/libgenerateDS/process_includes.py), but lxml by itself has no such functionality.