# How to import linked XSD files in LXML

Tags: python, xml, xsd, lxml

I am trying to load a few linked XSD files as an LXML schema, but I suspect they are not loading correctly via `<include>` and `<import>`.

**Does LXML require a manual import of each linked XSD file? If so, how does one go about it? If not, what is wrong with my approach below:**

The exact files I am referring to can be found here: https://github.com/NordPool/Day-Ahead-Public

After extracting the files and running python in the directory, I do the following:

```
from lxml import etree
xmlschema_doc = etree.parse('urn-ediel-org-neg-spotmarket-biddocument-1-0.xsd')
etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
```

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XMLSchemaParseError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-273-fd473f61b95f> in <module>()
      1 xmlschema_doc = etree.parse(xsdRoot + 'urn-ediel-org-neg-spotmarket-biddocument-1-0.xsd')
----> 2 etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)

src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:191759)()

XMLSchemaParseError: simple type 'LocalRestrictedAllocationModeType', attribute 'base': The QName value '{urn:entsoe.eu:wgedi:codelists}LocalAllocationModeType' does not resolve to a(n) simple type definition., line 5
```

Some of the XSD files are supposed to be in `../../core/`, but fixing the reference in the files to use the same directory does not actually fix the problem.

I have been assured that this validates in Altova XMLSpy.

Comment: That utility is probably doing a search. I would reproduce the directory structure or configure an xml catalog.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42395979/407651